# How can I recover a lost iDisk file?

Tags: macos, finder, mobileme

I recently had a file that was on my office computer (iMac) which was not syncing with my MacBook Air for some reason. I read that I should try to turn off iDisk and then re-activate. When I did this I lost the file that was on the iMac and can no longer find it.  This was a simple txt file with some important information in it.

Does anyone know if the file has been sent to a certain trash or similar? I would really like to recover this file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to this I was recently looking through my desktop to clean some things up and noticed a directory labeled Previous local iDisks and within this directory contained the iDisk that had been removed.  Note I am on osx 10.6.8.

Hopefully this helps someone else out in a similar predicament in the future.